# Storing mobile apps data to avoid data loss

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage

So I have hybrid apps (android and iOS) and it has some questionnaire which stores text, base64 images from(camera, phone gallery). it has over 50+ questions and each question can have an image depends upon the user.

1. Currently, it stores data in local storage (ionic storage) and when everything is filled it stores data to MongoDB. but some users have a really big amount of data and suddenly app crashes are it because local storage runs out of memory?
2. what is the best way to store offline data when they are filling a questionnaire.
3. if the app crashes what can be the way to restore the data. Because I was a developer cannot see anything on the database until they completely fill and click on the button (save) to the DB.

Comment: You can try web SQL..  similar to sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the local storage you can use "ionic sqlite storage" https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite, it is best way to store the offline data.

The possibility of app crashes using the sqlite storage is minimum. As we are using this to maintain offline data of more than 40 tables and 1 lakh rows using sqlite storage.